# How to copy raw memory to Buffer in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, node-ffi

I use `node` and `node-ffi`. I get a callback from native/C that passes a `(void *,size_t)` to indicate a memory region with interesting data. I'd like to take that and create `Buffer` with the same contents.

Basically:

```
function callback_on_write(ptr, size)
{
    var buffer = new Buffer(size);
    buffer.somehow_copy_from_memory(ptr, size);
}
```

How do I copy raw memory to `Buffer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ref.reinterpret(buffer, size, offset)`](https://tootallnate.github.io/ref/#exports-reinterpret).

> Returns a new Buffer instance with the specified `size`, with the same memory address as `buffer`.

```
var ref = require('ref');

function callback_on_write(ptr, size)
{
    var buffer = ref.reinterpret(ptr, size);
}
```