# Why is a `node-ffi` Callback returning an empty Buffer with `void *` but not with `int *`?

Tags: node.js, pointers, buffer, node-ffi

I'm working on implementing a callback using `node-ffi` with the following signature:

```
const callback = ffi.Callback('void', ['int', 'void *'], (eMsg, pData) => {
    console.log(pData);
    console.log(`Buffer deref: ${ref.get(pData)}`);
});
```

The underlying C library calls this with a `void *` value for `pData`. About half of the callbacks actually return an `int *` value and, in the other half, `pData` is more complex data (i.e. `Struct`). The `ref.get(pData)` ends up being `null`. If I change the `Callback` definition to use `int *` instead of `void *`, `ref.get(pData)` returns the correct value. What I can't figure out is why the `void *` ends up being a Buffer with a size of 0 that does *not* dereference properly (even when `pData` *is* an `int *`).

I feel like I'm missing something but can't, for the life of me, see what that would be. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476182/how-to-copy-raw-memory-to-buffer-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and what I did was set the `length` property of the returned Buffer to the size of the thing that will be returned.
Because it is `void *` type, node-ffi basically does not know how long of Buffer will be returned to it.

so in this case, `pData.length = <size of structure>` should fix it.